# SegFault with inputting a file

Tags: c

Here is my code. Edit: Caller included at the bottom.

This function reads in a datafile, determines how many rows and columns there are, and then stores the data into data_array.

```
int getdata(double* *data_array, int* *data_labels, int argc, char *argv[], int *items, int *attr)
{  
// filename variables
char *filename; // pointer to a string that will contain the name of the training data file.
char *result = NULL; // used with strtok() to extract each feature value given a line of delimited features.
FILE *fp; // pointer to FILE, we can use this with fgets to access each line
char line[10000];       // array of 1000 chars for storing the raw data for one observation
char delims[4];         // an array of common delimiters for data files
delims[0]='\t';
delims[1]=' ';
delims[2]=',';
delims[3]='\0';
int i, j;
// check that we have the correct number of command line arguments
if (argc < 2)
{
   printf("2usage: progname filename\n");
   return -1;
}

if (argc < 4)
{
   printf("3usage: progname filename num_labels k(nn)\n");
   return -1;
}

if (atoi(argv[2]) < 1)
{
    printf("num_labels must be a positive integer.\n");
    return -1;
}

if (atof(argv[2]) - atoi(argv[2]) > 0)
{
    printf("num_labels must be an integer.\n");
    return -1;
}

if (atoi(argv[3]) < 1)
{
   printf("k must be a positive integer.\n");
   return -1;
}

if (atof(argv[3]) - atoi(argv[3]) > 0)
{
   printf("k must be an integer.\n");
   return -1;
}

// try to open the file
filename = argv[1];
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
   printf("could not open file: %s\n", filename);
   printf("note: the filename should be the second command line argument, after the .exe file");
    return -1;
 }
 printf("reading file: %s\n", filename);

 // GET NUMBER OF ROWS AND COLUMNS OF INPUT FILE
 fgets(line, 10000, fp);
 result = strtok(line,delims);
 while(result != NULL)
 {
  (*items)++;
  result = strtok(NULL, delims);
 }  
  (*attr)++;
  while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp) != NULL)
  (*attr)++;

  printf("num items: %d\n", *items);
  printf("num attributes: %d\n", *attr); 


  // NOW THAT YOU HAVE FILE SIZE, ALLOCATE MEMORY TO STORE DATA
  *data_array = malloc(*items* *attr*sizeof(double));
  //*data_labels = malloc(*items*sizeof(int));
  printf("data array size = %d\n\n",*items* *attr);

  i=0;
  j=0;
  fclose(fp);
  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  // SAVE DATA INTO DATA_ARRAY
  while (fgets(line, 10000, fp) != NULL) 
  { 

  // we break line into tokens using our delimeters list declared at the beginning of the function
  result = strtok(line,delims);
  //printf("%d\n",i);
   while(result != NULL) {
   (*data_array)[i++] = atof(result);
   //printf("%f\n",(*data_array)[i-1]);
   result = strtok(NULL, delims);
   }
   //(*data_labels)[j++] = (int)((*data_array)[--i]);
   }
   // close the file
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      double *data_array = NULL;
      int *data_labels = NULL;
      int items = 0;
      int attr = 0;

      if (getdata(&data_array, &data_labels, argc, argv, &items, &attr) == -1)
      {
        printf("reading input data failed");
        return 0;
      }
      printf("PROCESS COMPLETED WITHOUT SEGFAULT");

      #ifdef CROSSVAL
      // v-fold cross-validation
      if (crossval(data_array, atoi(argv[2]), items, attr, closest_center, centers) == -1)
      {
        printf("k-means operation failed");
        return 0;
      }
      #else

      // coords holds coordinates of one new point
      int i;
      double coords[attr];
      for(i = 0; i<attr;i++)
      {
        coords[i] = atof(argv[i+4]);
      }
    /*
      // calling knn function
      if (knn(data_array, data_labels, atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]), coords, items, attr) == -1) // use a heap!
      {
        printf("knn operation failed");
        return 0;
      }
    */
      #endif

      free(data_array);
      return 0;
     }
```

The weird thing is this function outputs correctly before segfaulting.  Given a datafile with `2 columns and 272 rows`, i get "`num items: 2, num attributes: 272, data array size = 544"`.  But then if I comment out everything after the "`printf("num attributes: ...`" line and before the final `fclose(fp)` line, it still segfaults.  So it's getting through the print statements fine, then segfaulting even though there's no important code after it.  So confused.

Comment: Opportunity knocking to run this in a *debugger*.

Comment: Are you allocating memory for `double **data_array` properly?

Comment: You don't check whether the second `fopen` succeeds.

Comment: time to use valgrind...!!!

Comment: I'm fairly new to C and don't know a thing about debuggers, will check it out though.  double **data_array is allocated properly (I got this function working when I entered the dimensions of the array manually and just had the function store the data).  As for checking whether the fopen succeeds, even if I comment out the entire second fopen process it still segfaults.

Comment: In which platform are you developing this?

Comment: Not sure what that means.  I'm using notepad++ to write the C code and running it in cygwin.  If it helps I kept commenting out more and more until I eliminated the segfault.  The segfault occurs in the "  while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fp) != NULL)
    (*attr)++;" line and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Could you include the caller?

Comment: Included.  Another weird thing is that if I comment out everything after the file open except for "  while(fgets(line,10000,fp) != NULL)
    (*attr)++;" it still segfaults, but if I delete the "(*attr)++;" it no longer segfaults.  ???

Comment: by including the calling function, someone possibly located your error? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program segfaults after the call to `getdata()` in the `for` loop.

You don't check if there are enough arguments to your program and read `attr + 4` arguments, whether they exist or not.

This is also the reason, why it doesn't segfault, when you remove `(*attr)++`. Because then, `attr` remains `0` and you don't try to read non-existing arguments.